# what is the easiest way to have images next to the text on a html dropdown combobox

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, image, combobox, drop-down-menu

is there anyway to have image icons next to the text on dropdown list in html ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about the `<select>` tag then no, there isn't. You will have to roll your own dropdown or use some of the [existing](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown).